# safely unmount samba share in freebsd

Tags: freebsd, samba

I've mounted a samba share on my Freebsd 8.2 server. I tried sudo umount -a -t cifs -l as suggested by a number of users on forums. But this gave me "illegal argument -l" error when I tried it.

What's the best and safest way of unmounting a Samba share without crashing or restarting the server. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD's `umount` doesn't have a `-l` option. In addition, you need to use `smbfs` instead of `cifs`:

```
sudo umount -at smbfs
```